# Clear an interval when the last element is update

Tags: angular, ngrx

I'm trying to stop an interval when my last element is update.

I do not know how to do. Can you get me started on tracks?

At the moment I clear my interval when I leave the page.

```
    this.subscriptions.push(this.requestId.subscribe(id => {
        this.store.dispatch(new requestActions.LoadRequest(id));
        this.interval = setInterval(() => {
            this.store.dispatch(new requestActions.LoadRequest(id));
        }, 1700);
    }));
```

My effect :

```
@Effect()
loadRequest$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
    .ofType<requestActions.LoadRequest>(requestActions.LOAD_REQUEST)
    .switchMap(action => {
        return this.apiService
            .loadRequest(action.payload)
            .map((task: RequestTask[]) => new requestActions.LoadRequestSuccessAction(task))
            .catch(error => of(new requestActions.LoadRequestFailureAction(error)));
    });
```

my reducer :

```
    case request.LOAD_REQUEST_SUCCESS:
        console.log("Payload : ", action.payload);
        return {
            ...adapter.addAll(action.payload, state),
            loaded: true,
            selectedIndex: null
        } as State;
```

Comment: I don't get what you are trying to achieve honestly. Can you be more clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem by doing this:

```
export interface State extends EntityState<Event> {
request: Request }
```

I create a function

```
function getStatusOfEvents(payload : any){
const object = payload as Event[]
const events = object.map(obj => obj.status);

if (events.includes("PENDING")){
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
} }
```

I place the value in the store :

```
export function reducer(state: State = initialState, action: request.Actions): State {
switch (action.type) {
    case request.LOAD_EVENTS_SUCCESS:
        console.log("Payload events : ", action.payload);
        const status = getStatusOfEvents(action.payload)
        return {
            ...adapter.addAll(action.payload, state),
            refresh: status,
            loaded: true,
        } as State;
    case request.LOAD_EVENTS:
    case request.LOAD_EVENTS_FAILURE:
    default:
        return state;
}
```

}

And finally I "clear" my interval when the return value is false

```
refresh: boolean;

this.subscriptions.push(this.requestId.subscribe(id => {
        this.store.dispatch(new requestActions.LoadEvents(id));
        this.interval = setInterval(() => {
            this.store.dispatch(new requestActions.LoadEvents(id));
            this.store.select(fromRoot.getRefreshEntitiesState).subscribe(data => this.refresh = data)
            console.log("Refresh :", this.refresh)
            if (this.refresh != undefined && this.refresh === false) {
                clearInterval(this.interval);
            }
        }, 1700);
    }))
```

Answer (score 0):

add `error` and `complete` state.

```
this.subscriptions.push(this.requestId.subscribe(id => {
    this.store.dispatch(new requestActions.LoadRequest(id));
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
        this.store.dispatch(new requestActions.LoadRequest(id));
    }, 1700);
}),(err)=>{console.log(err);},
()=>{
    clearInterval(this.interval);
}
);
```

Comment: I'm trying today. Thx